# CSS triangles floating with their containers

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put some triangles made in css next to containers, 
one over the container in white (imitating the background)
and one in blue on the right side.

I tried several solutions, but by using absolute positioning of triangles, when I add an element above the absolutely positioned triangles it breaks their positioning. I also tried the triangles with `:after` and `:before`, and using `clear` for the container, but this did not work.

**CSS:**

```
#sortables {
padding: 15px;
}

.sortable {
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: #d2e0f2;
    padding: 5px;
}  

.sortable li {
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 3px;
}

.sortable li:hover {
    cursor: move
}

ul{
    margin:0;
}

.dimensions_container {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 160px;
    margin:10px;
} 

.triangle-right{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 170px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #d2e0f2;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 17px; 
} 

.triangle-left{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1px;
    left: 25px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent white;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 17px;
}  


.header {
    text-align:center;
    padding: 3px;
    width: 154px;
    background-color: #d2e0f2;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="sortables">
    <div class="dimensions_container">
        <div class="header">Available groups</div>
        <ul id="sortable1" class="sortable droptrue ui-sortable">
            <li id="undefined" class="ui-state-default">undefined</li>
            <li id="undefined" class="ui-state-default">undefined</li>
            <li id="undefined" class="ui-state-default">undefined</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="triangle-right"></div>
    <div class="dimensions_container">
        <div class="header">Grouped by</div>
        <ul id="sortable2" class="sortable droptrue ui-sortable"></ul>
    </div>
    <div class="triangle-left"></div>
    <div class="dimensions_container">
        <div class="header">Drill into</div>
        <ul id="sortable3" class="sortable droptrue ui-sortable"></ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: You can only use the `content` property with the `::after` and `::before` pseudo-elements

Comment: In your image, can you indicate where the triangles should go?  Outlines are good enough, thank you!

Comment: Why are you putting a white triangle on a white background? am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go. You'll find the code in this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xKzuX/

When using css arrows, it is better to use `:before` and `:after` pseudo selector on the parent with a `position: relative` on it (you had that part).

Then you absolute position the arrow (you had that part too but with wrong values).

To make it easy to reuse, I've reused your left/right classes. You can just add it wherever needed.

Finally, if your arrows render poorly in some browser, add `transform:rotate(360deg);` which make it do 360deg (so you won't notice the rotation at all) but it softens the edges.

Comment: Excellent it works like a charm! The transform of 360 trick its really a clever one, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use

```
position:relative
```

on the parent of your triangles (#sortables here).